# What are some ways to link two lists together in a dict like format in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, discord.py

I am developing a discord bot similar to Tamagotchi which accepts many commands. To reduce space usage and make the addition of new commands easier, I've adopted a two-dictionary approach. The first one, "COMMANDS," stores all accepted prompts for each command, while the second dictionary, "RESPONSES," links each command to its respective response.

Here's an example of the two dictionaries:

```
COMMANDS = {
    "wakeup": ["!goodmorning", "!wakeup", "!morning", "!wake"],
    "spit": ["!spit", "!ptoeey"],
    "punch": ["!punch"],
    "slap": ["!slap"],
    "kiss": ["!kiss"],
    "dance": ["!dance", "!play", "!jump", "!yippee", "!happy"],
    "pet": ["!pet", "!scritch"],
    "sniff": ["!sniff", "!jeffthekiller"],
    "sleep": ["!goodnight", "!sleep", "!night"],
    "bestfoods": ["!bestfoods", "!favorites", "!lovedfoods", "!yummys", "!yummies"],
    "goodfoods": ["!goodfoods", "!likes", "!goods", "!likedfoods"],
    "badfoods": ["!badfoods", "!bads", "!hates", "!hatedfoods"],
    "poisonfoods": ["!poisonousfoods", "!poison", "!poisons", "!dangerfoods", "!poisonfoods"],
    "eat": ["!eat"],
    "drink": ["!drink", "!slurp"],
    "status": ["!status"],
    "resurrect": ["!resurrect", "!live", "!rise", "!revive"]
}

self.RESPONSES = {
    "wakeup": self.wakeup,
    "spit": [""],
    "punch": [""],
    "slap": [""],
    "kiss": ["media/kiss.gif"],
    "dance": ["media/dance.gif"],
    "pet": ["media/normal_pet.gif", "media/fast_pet.gif", "media/slow_pet.gif", "media/squishy_pet.gif"],
    "sniff": ["media/sniff.gif"],
    "dead": ["media/dead.gif", "media/dead2.gif", "media/dead3.gif", "media/dead4.gif"],
    "sleep": self.sleep,
    "status": self.get_status_embed,
    "bestfoods": ("I love love love theese! " + "".join(self.stats["known_best_foods"])) if len(self.stats["known_best_foods"]) else "I don lolove anyfing........",
    "goodfoods": ("I like theese! " + "".join(self.stats["known_good_foods"])) if len(self.stats["known_good_foods"]) else "I don likke anyfing........",
    "badfoods": ("Thees arr GROSS!!! " + "".join(self.stats["known_bad_foods"])) if len(self.stats["known_bad_foods"]) else "I like everyfing!! Nuffins yuckyee",
    "poisonfoods": ("Thees HURTTT!!!!!! " + "".join(self.stats["known_poisonous_foods"])) if len(self.stats["known_poisonous_foods"]) else "Ai'm Invincble, nuffin hurts me!!",
    "resurrect": self.resurrect,
    "eat": self.eat,
}
```

To get a response, I joined the two dictionaries using commands and responses respectively. Here is the implementation:

```
for k, v in COMMANDS.items():
    if command[0] in v and k in self.RESPONSES:
        # If it's a list of responses, choose a random response
        if type(self.RESPONSES[k]) is list:
            responses.append(random.choice(self.RESPONSES[k]))
        else:
            # Else, it's a function reference. Process it
            response, action = self.RESPONSES[k](command)
            responses.extend(response) if type(response) is list else responses.append(response)
            actions.extend(action) if type(action) is list else actions.append(action)
```

I prefer this way because it separates data (commands and responses) from the code, which means I need to write less overall. However, the two dictionaries are getting messy, making it quite error-prone because I need to ensure that the keys between the two dictionaries match up.

Is there any way to link the two lists directly without the "command" in between? If this isn't possible, do you have any suggestions for other solutions to this problem?

Comment: It seems like your `COMMANDS` dictionary is backwards. It should be something like `{"!goodmorning": "wakeup", "!wakeup": "wakeup", ...}`. Then you wouldn't need to loop over it to find the match for the command.

Comment: I thought about that, but that would triple the length of the dictionary and negate the ease of prompts to a single command

Though it would allow easier lookup and, I'm sure, be more performant, I haven't run into any performance issues yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to use a nested dictionary that stores the aliases and responses for a particular command. This avoids having to check that the command is the same across two different dictionaries. Then, generate the alias to command dictionary from that using list comprehension:

```
bot_io = {
    "wakeup": {
        "alias": ["!goodmorning", "!wakeup", "!morning", "!wake"],
        "response": [self.wakeup],
    },
    "spit": {"alias": ["!spit", "!ptoeey"], "response": [""]},
}

alias_to_command = {alias: command for command in bot_io for alias in bot_io[command]['alias']}
```

Comment: I slightly tweaked the last bit of code to:`alias_to_command = {alias: bot_io[command]["response"] for command in bot_io for alias in bot_io[command]['alias']}`

this makes a dict where every alias is mapped to the correct response, which is exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to search linearly, there's no point in using a dictionary, use a list. You can make it a list of tuples or dictionaries that contain both the commands and responses.

```
commands = [
    {"commands": ["!goodmorning", "!wakeup", "!morning", "!wake"],
     "response": self.wakeup},
    {"commands": ["!spit", "!ptoeey"],
     "response": [""]},
    ...
]

for i in commands:
    if command[0] in i['commands']:
        if isinstance(i['response'], list):
            responses.append(random.choice(i['response']))
        else:
            response, action = i['response'](command)
            responses.extend(response) if type(response) is list else responses.append(response)
            actions.extend(action) if type(action) is list else actions.append(action)
        break
```